# Why arg1 and arg2 are undefined?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a wrapper function for setInterval() as mentioned in
[How to pass intervalID to interval function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35920606/how-to-pass-intervalid-to-interval-function-in-javascript?answertab=active#tab-top), however, I don't have access to arg1 and arg2 since they are undefined even though I have passed them to the setIntervalWarrper() as texts and 0. What just happened?

```
let texts = carouselHeading.querySelectorAll('span');

const setIntervalWrapper = (callback,time) => {
      let args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
      args[0] = setInterval(() => {
            callback.apply(null,args);
      }, time);
      console.log('arguments',Array.from(arguments),"time",time);
}

setIntervalWrapper((intervalID,arg1,arg2) => {
      console.log(intervalID,arg1,arg2);
      clearInterval(intervalID);
},50,texts,0);
```

Comment: Where are you defining arg1,arg2

Comment: `arguments` is not in arrow functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935336/official-information-on-arguments-in-es6-arrow-functions

Comment: Your setIntervalWrapper is getting callback and time as parameters, and you're passing arg1 and arg2 to that callback.